# How can I know if the given points form a 2d rectangle

Tags: c, math, geometry, computational-geometry

How to know if the given points can form a 2d rectangle? Assume that the user has to put 4 inputs:

```
Point 1: 0 0
Point 2: 20 0
Point 3: 20 50
Point 4: 0 50
```

How do I know if these given points form a 2d triangle or not? is there like a formula or something to follow? Please explain to me because I'm trying to understand!

This has to do with C because I'm programming it on C. If not, please move it to the relevant forum.

Comment: On a cartesian plane, pairs of coordinates must share x or y ordinates for a rectangle.  This question is probably better asked in another forum -- it's not really related to C.

Comment: @BrianCain Can you give an example please?

Comment: This question does not relate to programming as you have not asked a programming question, but a mathematics question.

Comment: @Frank when you mention "2d **triangle** or not" did you want to write actually "2d **rectangle** or not" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check for an **unrotated rectangle** (i.e., two vertical and two horizontal lines), then the co-ordinates will need to be of the form

```
(a,x)
(a,y)
(b,x)
(b,y)
```

(If you want to allow for rotations then you should look up scalar products: you'll need to check whether the lines have 90 degree angles between them.)

You also mention **triangles**. I'm not sure if that was intentional, or if you meant the whole question to be about **rectangles**.

Any three points will form a **triangle**, as long as they're not collinear (all in a line). If you want to know whether *four* points all lie on the edges of the same triangle, then you'll need to check that you have three points that are collinear and one that's not on that same line. That will mean that three of the points form the vertices of your triangle, and the fourth is somewhere on one of the edges.

(I can't think of another interpretation of your question with respect to triangles. Please clarify if that's not what you meant.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. So, if a user give the following points, would they still form a triangle? 
0 -4

4 0

0 4

-6 0

Comment: @frank no, you can't get three collinear points out of those four. Try plotting them on some graph paper.

Comment: @chiastic-security I think the OP wanted to write "rectangle" instead of "triangle".

Comment: @MichaelWalz oh, I see! I thought that was a follow-up question!

Comment: In any case, the points (0,-4) (4,0) (0,4) (-6,0) don't form a triangle or a rectangle, so I think OP needs to review basic geometry.